# Backbone JS : IE8 "toJSON()" not working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js with Handlebars.js templating library.

Everything works fine in all other browsers except IE8. I have finally narrowed down the problem to this.

In my Backbone View, I have the following

```
// rendering each events item in the list
render: function() {
    $(this.el).append(this.template({item:this.model.toJSON()}));
    return this;
}
```

It's fairly simple, and works on IE9. But on IE8, nothing gets displayed. It's just blank.
When I do

```
$(this.el).append(this.template);
```

It displays the outline of the view, so the template is working fine I think. So I think the problem lies in "item:this.model.toJSON()" part.

What's going on?

EDIT

CRAP. I had an extra "" element within my templating code, so I guess IE8 saw that it wasn't valid HTML (very strict?).

Comment: What does `$(this.el).append(this.model.toJSON);` print?

Comment: this.model.toJSON just clones your data and makes it an object. i dont think there is any problem. But the templating function might throw something. You need to debug this in IE. Btw, why you put the json object into an "item" placeholder? Why an extra object?

Comment: @Tomalak toJSON just does ´toJSON : function() { return _.clone(this.attributes);}´ there is nothing wrong with toJSON i think, again...

Comment: thanks Luke. You're right, there is no point of making an extra object, though I'm not sure if that is the problem. I got rid of it anyway, but IE8 is still not doing anything.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting a similar issue where after removing a model from my collection, the collection gets into a bad state and methods like toJSON or toArray no longer work when called on the collection object

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to include the [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Compatibility View` is turned off in IE.

Tools -> Compatibility View

Comment: it's turned off. doesn't change anything.